# In jquery xml parsing, how to retrieve a different set of xml data in different div,ul sections

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

```
$(xml).find("Tutorial").each(function()
{
  $("#output").append($(this).find("Title").text() + "<br />");
  $(this).find("Category").each(function()
  {
    $("#output").append($(this).text() + "<br />");
  });

  $("#output").append("<br />");
});
```

The above jQuery xml parsing code displays output as given below on a single div #output

Output:

```
 Silverlight and the Netflix API  //<div id="output">Silverlight and the Netf...</div>
 Tutorials           //<div id="output">Tutorials</div>
 Silverlight 2.0     //<div id="output">Silverlight 2.0</div>
 Silverlight
 C#
 XAML

 Cake PHP 4 - Saving and Validating Data
 Tutorials
 CakePHP
 PHP
```

but I need to display the output in the given below format

Output:                           //...

```
 Silverlight and the Netflix API  //<li>Silverlight and the Netf...</li>
 Tutorials           //<li>Tutorials</li>
 Silverlight 2.0     //<li>Silverlight 2.0</li>
 Silverlight        
 C#
 XAML                     //<li>XAML</li> </ul>

 Cake PHP 4 - Saving and Validating Data     //<ul> <li>Cake PHP 4 - Saving and..</li>
 Tutorials         //<li>Tutorials</li>
 CakePHP
 PHP               //<li>PHP</li> </ul>
```

note: the above code displays the output in single div only, but I need to get the first section of xml elements in-between one `<ul>` tag and another section of xml elements in another `<ul>` tag section.

pls help me for this...

I get this from a [tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/877/xml-parsing-with-jquery)

thanks in advance.

regards
Charles B.Michel

Comment: can you put on fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(xml).find("Tutorial").each(function()
{
  var $ul = $('<ul />'); //create a list for each section
  $ul.prepend($(this).find("Title").text() + "<br />");
  $(this).find("Category").each(function()
  {
    $ul.append($('<li />', {text: $(this).text() + "<br />"})); //append list item for every item in section
  });
  $ul.after('<br />')  
});
```

Is this what you are trying to achieve ?